# How to write a dynamic number of Eloquent queries in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

(This question is building on my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329240/laravel-how-to-write-two-inner-joins-with-a-count-statement-in-laravel-syntax))

There are four tables in my database:

1. `Users` (columns `id`, `dept_id`)
2. `Departments` (columns `id`, `deptStringName`)
3. `Absences` (columns `id`, `user_id`, `type_id`)
4. `Absence_types` (columns `id`, `stringName`)

At the moment there are 10 rows in the `Departments` table and 12 rows in the `Absence_types` table.

I'm trying to get a query that outputs ten tables, one for each department, with the types of absences and their counts next to the name, e.g., for the IT department:

```
+-----------+---+
| Sickness  | 4 |
| Paternity | 7 |
| Maternity | 3 |
| ...       | 6 |
+-----------+---+
```

I know the query to get these results. However, I'm wondering what is the best practice from a Software Engineering standpoint: do I **hard-code the values** in the `WHERE` clause as I've done (`dept.id = 1`) in the query below?

```
SELECT COUNT(abs.id) as AbsenceCount , absence_types.description FROM Absences abs JOIN Users u on u.id = abs.user_id JOIN Departments dept on dept.id = u.dept_id JOIN Absence_types on Absence_types.id = abs.type_id WHERE dept.id = 1 group by dept.description
```

Or do I use some other way to get the ID of a department? I can't think of a way in which I could write a Laravel script that would know how many departments there are and then run one query each per department.

**EDIT**: Example result could be like the one below (ideally), with A, B, C Absence Types for X, Y, Z Departments

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   | A | B | C |
+---+---+---+---+
| X | 4 | 8 | 5 |
| Y | 7 | 9 | 4 |
| Z | 5 |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Did you try a `foreach` loop over your departments?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel  I hesitated doing that as the query is called by a chart rendering code at the view side. That code requires one instance member call using `->` per query, i.e. 10 such calls for `Department` above

Comment: And you want one query for all departments?

Comment: If possible, yes. Something like a 2 dimensional table with Absence_types on the columns and Departments on the rows

Comment: Can you add an example result to your question?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, made the edits above

Comment: Your expected result involves pivoting (which I would do in PHP). I can think of two ways: First with one complex (and probably slow) query with a CROSS JOIN and a LEFT JOIN to a subquery. The Other with two or three queries. But nothing I can do in 5 minutes, and I have to run now. So I'll have a look at it later.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way..

Initialize the table by getting all departments and all absence types:

```
$departments  = DB::table('Departments')->pluck('deptStringName');
$absenceTypes = DB::table('Absence_types')->pluck('stringName');

$row = [];
foreach ($absenceTypes as $absenceType) {
    $row[$absenceType] = 0;
}

$table = [];
foreach ($departments as $department) {
    $table[$department] = $row;
}
```

This should create a 2D array like:

```
[
    'X' => [
        'A' => 0,
        'B' => 0,
        'C' => 0,
    ],
    // ...
]
```

You can use NULL or an empty string instead of `0` if you like.

Now modify your query a bit. You need to group by departments and absence types.

```
$data = DB::select('
    SELECT 
        d.deptStringName as department,
        t.stringName as absenceType,
        COUNT(a.id) as absenceCount
    FROM Absences a
    JOIN Users u         ON u.id = a.user_id
    JOIN Departments d   ON d.id = u.dept_id
    JOIN Absence_types t ON t.id = a.type_id
    GROUP BY d.deptStringName, t.stringName
');
```

And fill the `$table` with values fron the query:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $table[$row->department][$row->absenceType] = $row->absenceCount
}
```

Now the `$table` shlould look like

```
[
    'X' => [
        'A' => 4,
        'B' => 8,
        'C' => 5,
    ],
    'Y' => [
        'A' => 7,
        'B' => 9,
        'C' => 4,
    ],
    'Z' => [
        'A' => 5,
        'B' => 0,
        'C' => 0,
    ],
]
```